# Issues with pyinstaller and shared library (dll) - The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, dll, ctypes, pyinstaller

I have a python script which I want to convert to a standalone exe file. So,I am using pyinstaller. I have 2 dll files, which are written inc and c++, and are being used in python script using ctypes.

```
    global image_lib
    image_lib = ctypes.CDLL('image_lib.dll')

    global host_lib
    host_lib = ctypes.CDLL('host_lib.dll')
```

Both the files are in the current directory. Python script runs fine. Now I convert the python script to exe using pyinstaller, and add the dlls to the same folder, it works fine in my computer. But if I copy the same exe and the dlls to a different computer, only 'image_lib.dll' will be found. For some reason the exe is not able to find host_lib.dll which is in the same directly as well.

I also tried printing the path, where it is looking for dll, using application_path = os.getcwd(), and it is the current directory, but it is not able to find the dll in this directory.

I tried to add host_lib.dll in the hidden-import while generating exe using pyinstaller, but no luck.

I don't know what the problem could be, since one the issue is with just one dll and not the other. I really need help me with this.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I suspect host_lib.dll requires additional DLL imports to work properly.  Use a tool such as `dumpbin /IMPORTS host_lib.dll` to see what other DLLs it may require.

Comment: Thanks Mark!! I suspected the same and installed MinGW, and things start to work fine.